# cypher linked list concurrent inserts

Tags: neo4j, linked-list, cypher

**The problem**

I am trying to build a `linked list` using cypher and neo4j. The query works if the insertions takes place one at the time.

However If the inserts take place at the same time then the `linked list` becomes a mess.

**Illustration**
Blue nodes represent a group.
The yellow nodes represent posts. Those posts should be connected to the group as a linked list.

```
(GROUP)-[LAST_POST]->(POST)-[PREVIOUS_POST]->(POST)-...->(POST)
```

[image]

I understand that we cannot lock the writes to do one write at the time since that will affect performance. Is there a way to enforce a single `LAST_POST` relationship?

**The query I am using**

```
MATCH(group:group{id:{groupId}})
OPTIONAL MATCH (group)-[r:LAST_POST]->(oldPost) 
DELETE r                      
merge (post:post{id: {postId}, type:{type}})
CREATE (group)-[:LAST_POST]->(post) 
WITH post, collect(oldPost) as oldLatestPosts 
FOREACH (x in oldLatestPosts|CREATE (post)-[:PREVIOUS_POST]->(x)) 
RETURN post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by locking the node and releasing the it once I finish my manipulation.

The query should look something like the following:

```
MATCH(group:group{id:{groupId}})
SET group.__lock = true                     
WITH group
OPTIONAL MATCH (group)-[r:LAST_POST]->(oldPost) 
DELETE r                      
merge (post:post{id: {postId}, type:{type}})
CREATE (group)-[:LAST_POST]->(post) 
WITH group, post, collect(oldPost) as oldLatestPosts 
FOREACH (x in oldLatestPosts|CREATE (post)-[:PREVIOUS_POST]->(x)) 
SET group.__lock = false
RETURN post
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the old tail `...(POST)-[PREVIOUS_POST]->(POST)-...->(POST)` connected, then matching on the first element of the old list and connecting that element to the new head post is what you want to do.

```
MATCH(group:group{id:{groupId}})
OPTIONAL MATCH (group)-[r:LAST_POST]->(oldPost) 
DELETE r                      
MERGE (group)-[:LAST_POST]->(post:post{id: {postId}, type:{type}})
WITH post, oldPost
CREATE (post)-[:PREVIOUS_POST]->(oldPost) 
RETURN post
```